# How can I help out this cactus?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, cactus

Unfortunately I don't know the name of this cactus, How do I get rid of these little white things that is like a spider web?

she is dying :(

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a succulent of some sort, not a cactus. What you have are mealie bugs. Fortunately they can be removed and the plant should recover.

To get rid of mealie bugs pick as many off as possible. They also make egg cases that are smaller than the bugs, you need to pick those off too.

Opinions vary, but after you pick off as many bugs as possible (I use small tweezers), spray with a 70% rubbing alcohol solution.

You can also use a systemic pesticide, but mealies don't really require that.

It might take a few days/weeks to get it completely cleaned up, they'll keep re-appearing, but you just need to pick them off and spray.

In the mean time, remove all the dead leaves especially the dead material on top of the soil.

Keep things neat and tidy and try to improve airflow and you should be able to rid yourself of them.

Oh, if you have other plants, move this one away from them and carefully check them for mealies also.

Good luck, it's kind of a cool looking plant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I lost most of the leaves, but I hope they regrow

Comment: With that big stem it should be fine once you get the mealies under control. One other thing, does that pot have drainage holes in it? If not, you should either make some holes or put the plan in a pot with holes. Sitting in water is not good for succulent plants.